# First time form submission but from second time tis messing up, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to submit data for the first time only , from second time its not submitting properly.
https://codesandbox.io/s/form-submission-p1g0k8?file=/src/components/form.js

Answer (score 0):

Form is submitting on every submit click check your console for verification. Actually you are setting innerHTML in DOM on click and mapping the array. So you are changing array on handleChange i.e., on every value change so its pretending that submit button is not working but its working fine.

Comment: Oh okay thanks !! Appreciate !!